# Render a single jsp/html page side by side with different data (comparable view)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, jsp

We have a requirement to show 2 different data in side by side view.
Both views on 2 sides are exactly same only data is different.

How to achieve this using javascript in a better way?
Is there any resusable plugins available?

Anyone please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre> <html>
<head>
<script>
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="Page1">
    Content of page 1
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2');">Show page 1</a>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```